# Redux state updates outside of function but not inside of it

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to send the value of my redux state **receiver** to my back end, the only problem is that the value of my receiver inside that function that will send the state is different to the one outside of it.

**Note: This is not an issue of immutability/ component not re-rendering**

```
This is a snipped of my code:

 const { logged, receiver } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.loggedAndReceiver
  ); 

  console.log("Receiver1: ", receiver);



 async function getMessage(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target as HTMLElement;

    await dispatch(setReceiver(target.innerText));
    console.log("Receiver: ", receiver);

    try {
      const url =
        "http://localhost:3001/loadChat?logged=" +
        logged +
        "&reciever=" +
        receiver;
      const response = await fetch(url);

      const jsonData = await response.json();
      dispatch(setMessage(jsonData));

    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

In this code, log   `console.log("Receiver1: ", receiver);` is logging the latest version of the receiver, which is correct, the problem is the log inside my function `console.log("Receiver: ", receiver);` this one is logging the previous state, which is confusing me tbh, because the dispatch function above it is the only thing updating my redux state. So How am I supposed to use my redux state inside my function, and then send it to my server?

Comment: you cannot get the latest state after dispatching a state. because the latest state will be available on the next render.

Comment: Or you could try async thunk https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a race condition here.

If `target.innerText` is meant to be the new state, first send it as is on the `fetch` request and then update the store.